# Starting Druid to consume data from kafka

Tags: druid

Took the latest version of druid 0.16.0-incubating.

Had 2 question .

1) As mentioned in quick start , micro-quick-start doesnt work as it complains about no file jvm.config and main.config under /conf/druid/single-server/micro-quickstart/coordinator-overlord .

2) As micro qucik start failed i started to try with single-server-small.

Was trying to import data from kafka in single-server-small but unable to do so as it says extension is not loaded , by the way which i can see gets loaded in logs.

But i think my main problem is when ever i land up on 'Load data' Section on druid web page on localhost:8888 , it keeps me giving below error

"Failed to get overlord modules : Unable to determine destination for [/proxy/overlord/status]; is your coordinator/overlord running ?"

I can see my coordinator-overlord process up .

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete your kafka logs and druid logs(the location set up in common.runtime.properties) and then try again.